# Android In-app billing RESTORE_TRANSACTION usage

Tags: android, in-app-billing

Is there any example available on how to use RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS request to restore an In-app product purchase information? I came up with this code, but it always returns 0, so it doesn't recognize if the product is purchased or not: Everything is set up correctly.

```
Bundle request = BillingHelper.makeRequestBundle("RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS");

request.putLong("NONCE", 32436756l);
try 
{
    Bundle response = BillingHelper.mService.sendBillingRequest(request);
    int response_code = response.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE", -1);
    if (response_code == 0)
    {
    // Product purchased
    }
} 
catch (RemoteException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I found no examples on google and in the documentation, so any guidance would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this method:

```
public static void restoreTransactionInformation(Long nonce) 
    {
        if (amIDead()) 
        {
            return;
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "confirmTransaction()");
        Bundle request = makeRequestBundle("RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS");
        // The REQUEST_NONCE key contains a cryptographically secure nonce (number used once) that you must generate
        request.putLong("NONCE", nonce);
        try 
        {
            Bundle response = mService.sendBillingRequest(request);

            //The REQUEST_ID key provides you with a unique request identifier for the request
            Long requestIndentifier     = (Long) response.get("REQUEST_ID");
            Log.i(TAG, "current request is:" + requestIndentifier);

            //The RESPONSE_CODE key provides you with the status of the request
            Integer responseCodeIndex   = (Integer) response.get("RESPONSE_CODE");
            C.ResponseCode responseCode = C.ResponseCode.valueOf(responseCodeIndex);
            Log.i(TAG, "RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS Sync Response code: "+responseCode.toString());
        } 
        catch (RemoteException e) 
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed, internet error maybe", e);
            Log.e(TAG, "Billing supported: " + isBillingSupported());
        }
    }
```

, The call is as follows:

```
BillingHelper.restoreTransactionInformation(BillingSecurity.generateNonce());
```