# How to get inapp purchase data

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I integrated inappPurchase code to my android application.its working fine but i need handle 
purchase data because if user buy  my products after he uninstalled,after some days he again installed in the senario no need to purchase again.For this purpose how to handle data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the data that you place is removed when user Uninstalls the file, so basically create a file or folder with details of his accounts in an encrypted format either on the phone or on the SD card (preferably use Phone storage)

but again if user does a factory reset on his phone then all information will be lost

So

Either create a web service and pass all the account information , you can use the Phones IMEI number to act as a unique ID or use login info for the user so you can identify him or her even if he or she changes her phone

or use Google's GCM to target individual customers

EDIT

Ya restoring is there [Android In-app billing RESTORE_TRANSACTION usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563796/android-in-app-billing-restore-transaction-usage)

but what if your not using in built, but are using paypal SDK or some other methods then we have such the above mentioned options

Comment: RESTORE_TRANSACTION request will give you all purchased data. So you need to just give option to the application when application install in device first time or till user restores it. very simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should maintain all the purchase data on the server side for each device.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use RestoreTransactions function for getting the purchase data of the particular user.

```
mBillingService.restoreTransactions();
```

And in ResponseHandler.java file you will get all details in

```
public static void purchaseResponse(final Context context,
            final PurchaseState purchaseState, final String productId,
            final String orderId, final long purchaseTime,
            final String developerPayload, final String purchaseToken) {


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Items that are managed per user account can be purchased only once per user account. When an item is managed per user account, Google Play permanently stores the transaction information for each item on a per-user basis. This enables you to query Google Play with the RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS request and restore the state of the items a specific user has purchased.

Refer to this link:

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html

And read the section 'Choosing a Purchase Type'.